# React-native : Access to invalidated Results objects / already opened on current thread with different schema

Tags: react-native, realm

I have tried with One schema at a time approach.
when I try to close the DB facing issue :**Access to invalidated Results objects**

```
async fetchData(options) {
    const { schema, filter, sort, schemaName } = options;
        Realm.open({
          schema: [schema],
        }).then(realm => {
          let responseData = realm.objects(schema);
          if (filter) {
            responseData = responseData.filtered(filter);
          }
          if (sort) {
            responseData = responseData.sorted(sort);
          }
          resolve(responseData);
          realm.close()
        })
        }
```

And when I tried without close DB and switch 1 schema to another schema facing Got error
**:already opened on current thread with different schema.'**

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's not generally how Realm is opened. You need to use `const realm = await Realm.open({`. I would suggest reviewing the Getting Started Guide [Open & Close a Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/open-and-close-a-realm/#open-a-local-realm)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I managed to solve it just by closing the schema that was already open.

Do not leave more than one schema open. If there is, close the one that is open and you can open a new one.

What I did was the following:

```
// this is a index realm

import Realm from 'realm';

import {SomeObjSchema} from './schema';

function getRealmExpedition() {
  return await Realm.open({
    schema: [
      SomeObjSchema // your objects schema
    ],
    schemaVersion: 2, // your version
  });
}
```

And, in the file I want to open:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const realm = await getRealmExpedition();
  const data = realm.objects('SomeObjSchema'); // My ObjSchema name
  const dataWithFilter = realm.objects('SomeObjSchema).filtered('active == true')
  realm.close(); // this close current schema
};
```

EDIT:
The data that the Realm brings is not "changeable" without the Realm Write. They are Realm Objects and once you close the schema they will no longer be accessible.
Then you can take this data and convert it to JSON.

```
const stringObj = JSON.stringify(dataSchema);
const dataConverted = JSON.parse(stringObj);
```

So you can close the schema and use the data.